# Querying multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, query, join, subquery

I am working on a query from our ticketing system, and I am having problems figuring out the best way to join these tables together.

I have the following tables/fields:

```
SR_service: stores ticket data
  SR_Service_RecID
  SR_Status_RecID
  Last_Update
  Date_Req
company: defines a company
  Company_RecID
  Company_Name
SR_type: stores ticket type
  SR_Type_RecID
  Description
SR_Status: stores ticket status
  SR_Status_RecID
  Description
Schedule: the tickets assigned users, and date/time for work*
  RecID (This is the ticketID)
  Member_ID
  Date_Time_Start
  Date_Time_End
```

*The SCHEDULE table also has a Schedule_Type_RecID, and we are pulling for type '4'. If we join this table with SR_Service, only schedules of type '4' are allowed to be related to tickets in the system.

The first sub-query is for the type of ticket I am looking for. The type of ticket is dependent on what 'board' the ticket belongs to. Leaving out @Board will give me the type of ticket I'm looking for, across all boards.

The second sub-query is making sure I only get tickets that are in NOT closed status. Again, the closed SR_Status_RecID is dependent on the board. I return the closed status of all boards here.

I am at a loss how to get the ticket, company info, schedule info, and ticket status all in one query. The following is the list of what I need: Ticket_ID, status, assigned resources, company name, last update, and required date.

So far, I have come up with:

```
SELECT s.SR_Service_RecID, s.SR_Status_RecID, c.Company_Name, s.Last_Update, s.Date_Req
FROM SR_Service s INNER JOIN Company c ON s.Company_RecID = c.Company_RecID
WHERE SR_Type_RecID IN (SELECT t.SR_Type_RecID
                        FROM SR_Type t INNER JOIN SR_Board b
                        ON t.SR_Board_RecID = b.SR_Board_RecID
                        WHERE t.description LIKE @Type
                           AND b.Board_Name LIKE @Board)
AND s.SR_Status_RecID IN (SELECT SR_Status_RecID
                          FROM SR_Status
                          WHERE Closed_Flag = 0)
```

This will get me a good amount of data, but there are a few problems:

- I only get the status_ID, not the actual description of the status.
- I am not quite sure how to add the Schedule table into the query to determine when a person is schedule out to perform the ticket tasks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will get you the Status Description:

```
SELECT s.SR_Service_RecID, SR_Status.Description, c.Company_Name, s.Last_Update, s.Date_Req
FROM SR_Service s 
    INNER JOIN Company c ON s.Company_RecID = c.Company_RecID
    INNER JOIN SR_Status ON s.ST_Status_RecID = SR_Status.SR_Status_RecID
WHERE SR_Type_RecID IN (SELECT t.SR_Type_RecID
                        FROM SR_Type t 
                        INNER JOIN SR_Board b
                            ON t.SR_Board_RecID = b.SR_Board_RecID
                        WHERE t.description LIKE @Type
                           AND b.Board_Name LIKE @Board)
AND s.SR_Status_RecID IN (SELECT SR_Status_RecID
                          FROM SR_Status
                          WHERE Closed_Flag = 0)
```

To add the schedule, you'd need to add a key field from the `schedule` table to the `SR_Service` table.